# Is microphone quality different for iPhones and iPads?

Tags: iphone, ipad, audio, microphone

Should there be any significant difference in quality between the iPad Pro 10.5 and iPhone 7 Plus, with respect to internal microphone quality?

My iPad Pro seemed subjectively worse at dictation, so I setup a quick test:

- Removed cases from devices, ensured clear path to microphones
- Recorded a .wav sample to playback to the two devices, to test
  dictation, so the input wouldn't change.
- Held bothe devices microphones about three inches away from the test speaker.

The iPad Pro has been consistently worse in these tests, even though it also has a dual mic setup. I speak pretty neutrally, without an accent.

Is it expected that iPad should be worse?  Any ideas to explain the difference?

Comment: [Small holes on the iPad](https://i2.wp.com/9to5mac.files.wordpress.com/2017/05/ipad-mic.jpeg?w=1112&h=556&crop&quality=82&strip=all&ssl=1&zoom=2) compared to the [iPhone 7 Plus?](https://d3nevzfk7ii3be.cloudfront.net/igi/G1AmZxx3XP6PcIkE.medium) I couldn't find any info on the ICs used, so this isn't the gospel by any means.

Comment: @JMY1000 - thanks, it is very odd that such a thing would not have a clue in the specs or posts online. trying to think of any flaw in my testing methodology.